# Issue with UIImagePicker rotation

Tags: iphone, rotation, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape

I have set an UIIMagePicker in my app with:

```
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    imagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    imagePickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;
    imagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    //imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform =  CGAffineTransformScale(imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, 1.0, 1.3);
    imagePickerController.delegate = self.overlayView;
    [self.view addSubview:imagePickerController.view];
    imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView =self.overlayView.view;
```

All good and fine while the app is in portrait mode. Yet, if I rotate it in landscape a strange issue happen: a black bar appears on the right side and the view is 'rotated', in the sense that if I move the iPhone upward the image moves to the side and viceversa.

If I start in landscape mode, the black bar does not appear (it conversely shows when I rotate to portrait mode on the bottom), but the funny rotating behavior happens all the same.
In both cases the overlay screen seems to fill the screen and also correctly handle rotation.

What might be the issue and how to fix it?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue on iPad device running iOS 8.0.2. Did you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: Nope, I ended up limiting the usage to the portrait mode and this is of course really a shame.